# How to compare two binary codes, when sliding is permitted?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I am writing a program to compare two 1023-bit codes and detect if one is the same as the other; and if not, if they can be made the same by sliding the bits (by performing left or right rotations).

So I am concerned with checking whether the bits of the codes are in the same order and can be made equal by sliding of the bits in either code.

For example:
Code 1: 110101011
Code 2: 101111010

The Algorithm must give the codes to be equal since I can get Code 2 from Code 1 by sliding the bits of Code 1 by 5 to the right. Is there a better way of doing this rather than performing an AND operation to check equality and then a bitwise shift for the sliding?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to build this and benchmark it to see how fast it is, but you can make Code 3 by concatenating two copies of Code 2 together, construct a [Generalized Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) out of Code 3, and then look at whether it contains a copy of Code 1.

This will be a `O(n)` algorithm where `n` is the length of your code.